# Annoying auto moving of content

Tags: html, css

I have used StackOverflow for some time now, but now I have a question... On the site that I am developing, (a temporary Dropbox hosted site) I have run into an issue.  When the page is being resized, the center logo movies with the resizing.  I wish for everything to be fixed (as in not moving with resize). How do I do this?!  Thanks in advance, here is the site:
www.bit.ly/FawcettCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean fixed to the left edge. It's just a matter of removing `margin:auto` from the wrapper.

While you're at it you should remove the right-click disabling script. It serves no purpose except to be a nuisance for your users. People who want to steal content or print will just disable javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by making the postion of the wrapper absolute and then work on the margins to place it where you want to display it. It will be placed at different position based on screen size though.

```
wrapper {
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
width: 940px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can fix  your center logo as you wants to display where in your page.....
You can play with the positions and display your logo as you want.
till that here is **CSS** for center logo fixing:-

```
#wrapper {
left: 371px;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
width: 940px;
```

}